# Accidentally deleted openssl lib packages and can't get yum

Tags: redhat

Accidentally deleted openssl lib packages and can't get yum or wget to work again

can anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

I do not have access to *redhat* repositories but, assuming you are running *redhat-7*, this should be fetchable using plain `http`.  You can then install using rpm or yum install local.

```
http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/centos/7.7.1908/os/x86_64/Packages/openssl-1.0.2k-19.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

For other versions of *RHEL* just go to `rpmfind.net` and search for a suitable package.  Once you have ssl working then use yum to reinstall the official package.

If you absolutely cannot get the package any other way; and given that you state that you are using RHEL-6.10; then you can try this:

```
# ftp ftp.tugraz.at
Connected to ftp.tugraz.at (129.27.3.13).
220 ProFTPD 1.3.5b Server (ftp.tugraz.at) [::ffff:129.27.3.13]
Name (ftp.tugraz.at:root): anonymous
331 Anonymous login ok, send your complete email address as your password
Password:
230-Welcome!
. . .
230 Anonymous access granted, restrictions apply
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.

ftp> get pub/mirror/centos/6.10/updates/x86_64/Packages/openssl-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64.rpm /tmp/openssl-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64.rpm

local: /tmp/openssl-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64.rpm 
remote: pub/mirror/centos/6.10/updates/x86_64/Packages/openssl-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64.rpm

227 Entering Passive Mode (129,27,3,13,142,21).

150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for 
    pub/mirror/centos/6.10/updates/x86_64/Packages/openssl-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64.rpm (1601792 bytes)

226 Transfer complete
1601792 bytes received in 1.69 secs (945.92 Kbytes/sec)

ftp> quit
```

Comment: i am using the RHEL 6.10 and can you please let me know the commands to run and fix it..

Comment: `wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos-6/6.10/os/x86_64/Packages/openssl-1.0.1e-57.el6.x86_64.rpm` will retrieve the openssl rpm package from CENOS.org. This is a  rebuild of the actual RH package.  WGET will save it to the system you are running it on in the directory that you run `wget` from.  Then use `yum install </path/to/rpm file>`.  Once OpenSSL is reinstalled then use `yum reinstall openssl` to replace the CentOS version with the official Redhat package. Bear in mind that this is not tested and not guaranteed to work.  I have used this method in the past and it has for me.

Comment: You should check `/etc/yum.repos.d/what-ever-Base.repo` to see if you actually need https to get the packages from Redhat.

Comment: Last, if you are running RHEL then you should be able to register your system and get support directly from RH.

Comment: yum,wget were not working to download the rpm . getting the error as (libssl.so.10:cannot open shared object file : no such file or directory

Comment: Open up a web browser such as Firefox or Chromium.  Put the following URL in the address: `ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/ftp.centos.org/6.10/updates/x86_64/Packages/openssl-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64.rpm`.  Save the rpm package locally.

If you are not running the browser on the system with the problem then copy the file over to it  using a flash drive s intermediary if nothing else works.

Comment: Have you looked in `/var/cache/yum/x86_64/6/updates/packages` to see if you have the last update rpm still available?  Of course, this requires that `keepcache = 1` is set in `/etc/yum.conf`,and is not likely given the situation. But it is worth a look.

Comment: looked in /var/cache/yum/x86_64/6/updates/packages and had the rpm and installed the package and now it is working fine.

Comment: Glad it worked out.